# What do you mean by , HDFS does not support multiple writers?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Files in HDFS may be written to by a single writer.There is no support for multiple writers or for modifications at arbitrary offsets in the file. What do you mean by single writer and multiple writer? Could anybody please clarify?

Answer (score 4):

HDFS implements a single-writer, multiple-reader model. This means that you can have multiple readers read a file on HDFS but only one writer can write to that file. This model makes that concurrency control requirements more easy to implement. It is also simplifies data coherency and enables high-throughput access to files hosted on HDFS.

Keep in mind that writers in HDFS only appends to a file. If you have multiple writers (concurrent writers), how you are going to implement content appending without loosing data, damaging file's content and guarantee data integrity?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Does these multiple writers , mean , at a physical level multiple writers or it's at programming level?

Comment: @PradoshKumarJena Physical multiple writers?

Comment: I meant , how exactly the writers and readers are implemented at filesystem level so that HDFS is able to follow the " single writer , multiple reader " mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

That is fine and will enable high READ throughput but keep in mind HDFS was not designed with concurrency support in mind. While the writer is performing the job it will end up creating a NEW FILE as we do not have UPDATEs available. So , do not recommend to implement any type of control file solution based on HDFS.

Answer (score -4):

- A user or an application can create directories in HDFS and store
  files inside these directories. The file system namespace hierarchy
  is similar to most other existing file systems; one can create and
  remove files, move a file from one directory to another, or rename a
  file.
- For updating any file user has to update the file outside the HDFS
  and reload them to HDFS removing the existing one. Append is
  supported in Hadoop2